# Яке слово прийшло скорше в українську мову «рис» чи «риж»?

Tags: етимологія, запозичені-слова

Слово «рис» або «риж» індо-іранського походження, споріднене словам пушту wriže і санскриту vrīhi («рис»). Пізніше слово потрапило до грецької мови як óryzon або óryza, потім до латинської як oryza, давньофранцузької ris[4], звідки слово потрапило до української мови ймовірно аж у 19-му столітті через ланцюжок інших європейських мов.
Отже, яке найстарше слово «рис» чи «риж»... можливо оба с тих самих часів походження?

Answer (score 1):

> <sub>Етимологічний словник української мови Інституту мовознавства ім. О.О. Потебні НАН України.</sub>
>
> [РИС](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81#10720) «Oryza sativa L.» (ботанічне)
>
> - через російське (рис) і через польське (риж) посередництво запозичено із середньоверхньонімецької мови;
> - [серендьонімецька] *rīs* ([нововерхньонімецька] *Reis*) походить від [італійська] *riso*, яке через [середньолатинська] oryza зводиться до [грецька] ὄρυζα, а це останнє через іранське посередництво ([афганістанська] vrižē, [перська] birindž) – до [давньоіндійська] vrīhí- «тс.»;
> - буковинські форми [ориз, вориз] походять від [болгарська] ори́з (пор. [румунська] oréz «тс.»), що, як і [македонська] ориз, [сербохорватська]. орѝж, орѝз, зводиться безпосередньо до [грецька] ὄρυζα;
> - російська *рис*, білоруська *рыс*, польська ryż, чесьја rýže, словацька ryža, сербохорватська *рѝжа*, *ри́жа*, *ри̑ж*, словенська ríž;
>
> Фонетичні та словотвірні варіанти: *вориз*, *ориз* «рис»; *рижи́сько*, *рижівка* «рисове поле»; *рисі́вка*, *ріж* «Oryzopsis Mill.»

Час, на жаль, не вказаний. Але, схоже, ранїше панівним був *риж*, в тому числї на теренах під Москівщиною. Таку думку підкрїпюють [старі словники](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81&scope=all&dicts=all&no_accents=on&highlight=on):

> <sub>М. Уманець, А. Спілка: *Словарь росийсько-український 1893–1898 рр.*</sub>
>
> **Рисъ** = **риж**. С. З. Л. — *Вези овес до Парижу, а не буде з вівса рижу*. н. пр.

Варто зазначити, що в прикладї згадана приказка:

> <sub>В. В. Жайворонок: *Знаки української етнокультури: Словник-довідник.* — К.: Довіра, 2006. — С. 410.</sub>
>
> [**ове́с**](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/zhaivoronok_znaky_ukrainskoi_etnokultury/%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81) (зменшене — *овесе́ць*, *овесо́к*)
> […] ра­зом з тим рослина вважалася ма­лопоживною: «Вези овес хоч до Парижу, а не буде з вівса рижу»; вівсяний хліб вважався голодним.

---

> <sub>Б. Грінченко: *Словарь української мови 1909 р.*</sub>
>
> **Риж**, **-жу**, м. Oryza satira L, рисъ. Ном. № 75S8. Котл. Ен. IV. 67. ЗЮЗО. І. 130.

Як можна побачити, згаданий один письменик і твір, де теж є [словничок](//uk.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%97%D0%B4%D0%B0_(1798)/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA):

> <sub>Котляревський: *Енеїда*</sub>
>
> *Малороссійскихъ словъ содержащихся въ Энеидѣ, и сверхъ того еще весьма многихъ иныхъ, издревле вошедшихъ въ Малороссійское нарѣчіе съ другихъ языковъ, или и коренныхъ Россійскихъ, но не употребительныхъ.*
>
> Рижъ, сорочинское пшено.

Тут *сорочинське* або ж [*сарацинське*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8) позначає мусульман, не обовязково арабів. Тобто, скорїш за всього, тоді москівська ще не мала слова *рис* або якщо і було, то геть непоширене.

---

> <sub>О. Ізюмов: *Російсько-український словник 1930 р.*</sub>
>
> **Рис**, бот. – риж, -жу.

---

> <sub>А. Ніковський: *Словник українсько-російський 1927 р.*</sub>
>
> **Риж**, **-жу** – рис.

---

Є ще така робота:

> <sub>С. А. Яценко: *Назви продуктів харчування, страв і напоїв" в українській мові XIV – XVII століть*</sub>
>
> Імовірно, що слово *рыжъ* (*рижъ*) «рис» потрапило до української мови саме в староукраїнську добу (засвідчене в 1561 р.): *камень рыжу*. Воно вжито тільки з єдиним значенням – «зерно, призначене для приготування страв», адже рис в Україні не вирощували. Це підтверджує також виявлена словосполука *каша рыжовая*: *каша рыжовая зъ шафраном* (1572). Здебільшого назву відзначено у фонетичній формі *рыжъ* (1642). Слово через польське посередництво запозичено із середньоверхньонімецької мови. У сучасній українській літературній мові функціонує у формі *рис*, яке є новим запозиченням через російську з тієї ж середньоверхньонімецької мови. У говірках південно-західного наріччя назву вживають у старій формі *риж*.

---

Тобто більшість праць наразї поки указують, що *риж* прибув ранїше, а якщо будить доведено зворотньо, то був щонайменше панівним.